# Download multiple files asynchronously with one Progress Bar with cancellation

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, progress-bar

As you see from the title I need to have asynchronous multiple files downloading with a progress bar that illustrates the progress of the overall download and a cancelation option button for overall download operation. All this I need to implement in C#.

I am a beginner in C# and as I understand from others answer and about 3 hours of Googleing I need to create a background thread for cancelation option and I need to have multiple WebClients(because they aren't support multithreading) to download each file. I've written version in which I can download files asynchronously, but I don't know how to provide cancelation button in that case and information about overall upload(because threads run asynchronously). Overall I can't figure out how to mix this up, because as I see it I must have background thread and that multiple WebClients threads in background thread's doWork function, but even in that case if I click on cancel button it will stop only background thread and not other threads which downloading files(maybe I need to create that threads as background threads child threads and that problem will be solved?).
Here is the main part for asynchronous downloading(I'll skip implementation of other functions for simplicity). And I have a question here too, in this way it creates 38 threads(that's the number of files I am downloading), but I have 2 cores with hyperthreading, so 4 logical cores, how to prevent program from creating more than 4 threads and give a condition to run next downloading in a thread that will be free firstly.

```
private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (String url in urls)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        String filename = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/'));
        string downloadToDirectory = directory + filename;
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), downloadToDirectory);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I guess you have to do reporting on the total file Size. Asuming of course the other side tell you the maximum size (it is not a guarantee). The big issues is getting a class for the download that actually gives you progress reporting on that level. Otherwise you would have to disect/reverse engineer the download code to that level.

Comment: You should look into [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @pnavk I got what I need to do with SemaphoreSlim for threads count, thanks